# Is it possible to have dynamic type based on another type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a type like this:

```
type PageList = 'login' | 'register' | 'dashboard'
```

For every page, it has a different object to send, for example:

```js
const PageParam = [
  { 
    login: {
     isAuthenticated: true
    }
  },
  { 
    register: {
     isRegistered: false
    },
  },
    
]
```

And I need to use it in function like this:

```js
function moveTo(pageName: PageList, bodyParam: ???) {
  /* Some Logic */
}

// I want it goes this way
// JUST EXAMPLE!!
if (pageName === 'login') typeof bodyParam = { isAuthenticated: boolean }
if (pageName === 'register') typeof bodyParam = { isRegistered: boolean }
```

I need those *bodyParam* to have type following the *pageName* so I can send the right param without checking the type file again.

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can set up the equivalent of a dictionary of types:

```
type PageParam = {
    login: {
        isAuthenticated: boolean
    },
    register: {
        isRegistered: boolean
    },
    dashboard: {}
}

function moveTo<T extends PageList>(pageName: T, bodyParam: PageParam[T]) {
  /* Some Logic */
}

moveTo('login', {
    isAuthenticated: true // Okay
})

moveTo('register', {
    isAuthenticated: true // Error: Argument of type '{ isAuthenticated: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ isRegistered: boolean; }'
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgcwgGQJYGdhQLxQOQA2A9gqgHZ5QA++AThKZhLZTXgCZzoAWARkXFrs8AKBGhIsRBHi04AWxxQA3iKjqoxUmQBcKtRsMYAggFdg3CGWCoAxnGAR2e-kQIQ4ZA+oC+AGm8oekZHWj1VQyN0ACUGDFCnFyI3Dy9Df0DOHn5BZxUfEQKRADNTMlsbIjIoeSIANwgAFSIAHkaoCAAPRzJ2dCkkNEwAPgAKMGkAOQUIPUa-KH52EFkFPXgkVfkAbUaAXQBKfXUAegAqKABlInloZBI7KDOTwrFahubRwgeKBYiNEzmSzWOwORJQYC0UzQE4nKAAeQA1nAQIUDm96k0iF9gvFmHg-oFARYrDZ7I48pDoVBYVAAKK0WhEMJQYy0BCmW7WKBEYoQ8DQPDKKDE4FksF5VzuTwAbigPkoGCgZCIWC46FQCDIcF47ghRCgEzkt1CPL5EkFwowsRCzHBUtScoVaJEQA)

Comment: Might wanna be careful with using `{}` there since anything that is not null or undefined can be assigned to it...

Comment: Thanks! I never thought about this way before, It solves my problem